# Predicate to read integers from file in (swi) prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I was browsing the IO manual pages in swi-prolog and couldn't find a predicate to read integers (or numbers) from a file/stream. Didn't find anything on google either :|

I know how to write one, just wondering if there is something built-in since I guess that it would be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, there is library(dcg_basics) in the "http" package. It has a DCG non-terminal number//1, and you can use it with library(pio), i.e., phrase_from_file/2, to read directly from a file (without having to read the whole file at once). There was some discussion on the mailing list to include library(dcg_basics) in the core libraries, if you are interested check the archives and send a mail to the list. I think it would be a very useful addition to the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you can split your input up into a char list for each number, the [charsio library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.5%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/charsio.html%27%29%29) has this predicate:

`read_from_chars(+Codes, -Term)`

that will read a term from a list of chars without expecting a terminating period.

The [readutil library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.21%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/readutil.html%27%29%29) has predicates for reading char lists from streams, for example:

`read_stream_to_codes(+Stream, -Codes)`

It should be straightforward to split the codes list into sublists (comma or space delimited ?)